# Select element by attribute without jQuery

Tags: javascript

How can I target elements like this jQuery selector, but without using jQuery?

```
var header_elements = $("[data-automationid=SiteHeader]");
```

Explanation: I want to target the element that has a `data-autonmationid` attribute with the value of `SiteHeader`

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('[data-automationid=SiteHeader]');`

Comment: Someone else downvoted, been answered. My result by the way will return an array since you stated header element's, plural.

Comment: @File — `querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList, not an array.

Comment: If you wish to target the element using CSS3 here is a whole artical on it... as per the website there are 7 way to handle this based on the complexity

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/#the-seven-different-types

Comment: @Quentin Correct, which may be accessed by indexes. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `document.querySelector()` for one result or `document.querySelectorAll()` for a NodeList result.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

```js
document.querySelector('[data-attr=this]').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

```html
<div>not this one</div>
<div data-attr="this">this one</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select it by

```
const header_elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-automationid="SiteHeader"]');
```

document.querySelector => one element

document.querySelectorAll => multiple elements as NodeList